# Regarding stdio.h

Tags: c, header-files

Confession: I am a novice.

Question: I was checking out `stdio.h`, but I could not find the definition of the `fopen` function. Can somebody please tell where can I find the definition?

regards,

bug.

Comment: what compiler and operating system are using?

Comment: Do you mean the 'declaration' of the fopen function?

Comment: os: mac os x 10.5.8; gcc 4.0.1

Comment: I meant that the declaration is already there. I am / was looking for the definition.

Comment: @bug: we seem to have a problem with the terminology here. What is  a definition for you? The function prototype? The source code of the function itself? The library that defines the symbol?

Comment: @Jens Gustedt: declaration(function prototype) is this: void func(void); definition is: void func(void) {printf("thank you all for your help");}.

Answer (score 4):

the *declaration* should be in stdio.h (afaik the standard requires this), but it's not likely you're going to find the *definition* there*. If you are using an open source os, it probably has packages containing source code (containing the definition) you can download. Else, sorry, no definition available.

*supposing the author considers *definition* to mean the actual implementation whereas *declaration* rather refers to function prototype

Comment: Even on Windows, the source code for the CRT is available if you have Visual Studio installed. For example, the source for `fopen` can be found in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\crt\src\fopen.c`, or similar.

Comment: you're right, but I think you only get it if you buy VS, no? Or is it available with the Express versions as well?

Answer (score 3):

If you're using unix or linux you can find it with:

```
man fopen
```

Otherwise, just google for *[man fopen](http://www.google.com/search?q=man+fopen)* and you'll find it.

You can use `man` for pretty much any standard library function.

Comment: This is not the answer he is looking for. He wants to find the line in stdio.h where the fopen function is defined.

Comment: That's not what he said. He asked, "*Can somebody please tell where can I find the definition?*"

Answer (score 3):

You can find the definitions of functions in stdio.h here:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stdio.h

And here's an article on C file io:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_file_input/output

Answer (score 2):

```
extern FILE *fopen (__const char *__restrict __filename,
                    __const char *__restrict __modes) __wur;
```

As you said, in `stdio.h`.

Comment: Where is `stdio.h` likely to be located?

Comment: On UNIX systems, in `/usr/include`.

Answer (score 2):

http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/glibc/ 
There you can find c std. library source code

Answer (score 0):

alternatively, you can go on http://cplusplus.com/  under reference -> C Library -> cstdio (stdio.h)

Comment: This is a reference for stdio.h, but it doesn't answer the question, 'where can I find the definition for fopen'. He's looking through source code, trying to find a line of code.

Answer (score 0):

I found sourcecode [here.](http://www.koders.com/c/fid4AC8E5A6CAFCF1D081122F3CA5866F8ADCA5D1C4.aspx) am not a C-Coder so check the result for yourself. As far as I can tell, it looks like a real implementation. But even if it is not the "true" implementation it can at least give some hinds for the learning eyes. So it should be helpful, to know this file.

Answer (score 0):

The implementation of `fopen( )` for OS X (which is what the questioner is asking about) is available on opensource.apple.com:

http://opensource.apple.com/source/Libc/Libc-498.1.7/stdio/fopen-fbsd.c

I am curious, however, as to why you're looking for it; part of the point of libraries is that you don't need to know the details of how they work in order to use them effectively -- you need only know how to link against them and what the functions are defined to do.